# Google maps Установка только одного маркера

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Прошу помощи так как абсолютно не понимаю в javascript.

При клике на карту, появляется маркер , и появляется табличка для заполнения.
Если выбрать другое место , предыдущий маркер остается видимым на карте, а хотелось бы убрать.

Заранее благодарен .

[image: Для наглядности]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>API Google Maps v3 добавление меток пользователями и вывод их по категориям</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBNm_E5s9GF0ISJ5vAJIfrx_1s3WboNu_8&sensor=false"></script> 
 
<script src="/mapa/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.910511,33.391734);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
 
     var html = "<table>" +
                         "<tr><td>Наименование:</td> <td><input type='text' id='name'/> </td> </tr>" +
                         "<tr><td>Адрес:</td> <td><input type='text' id='address'/></td> </tr>" +
                         "<tr><td>Тип:</td> <td><select id='type'>" +
                         "<option value='bar' SELECTED>Бар</option>" +
                         "<option value='restaurant'>Ресторан</option>" +
                         "<option value='cafe'>Кафе</option>" +
                         "</select> </td></tr>" +
                         "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Сохранить' onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr></form>";
 
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: html
    });
 
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: event.latLng,
          map: map
        });
        
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }); 
    
    
  }
 
 

  function saveData() {
      var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
      var address = escape(document.getElementById("address").value);
      var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
      var latlng = marker.getPosition();
 
      var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=" + name + "&address=" + address +
                "&type=" + type + "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng();
      downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
        if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
          infowindow.close();
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Данные добавлены.";
        }
      });
    }
 
    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;
 
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request.responseText, request.status);
        }
      };
 
      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }
 
    function doNothing() {}
</script> 
 
<style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
#map_canvas { float:left; width:600px; height:400px; border:1px solid #000;} 
</style>
 
</head> 
<body onload="initialize()"> 
      <div id="map_canvas"></div> 
    <div id="message"></div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Как убрать маркер с Google карт](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove)

Я добавил вот эти строчки:

```
// переменную для маркера необходимо объявить где 
// то в теле скрипта, но не в теле метода обработки клика
var marker; 
...
// при обработке клика если marker не undefined 
// удаляем его перед добавлением нового
marker && marker.setMap(null);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>API Google Maps v3 добавление меток пользователями и вывод их по категориям</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBNm_E5s9GF0ISJ5vAJIfrx_1s3WboNu_8&sensor=false"></script> 
 
<script src="/mapa/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

  function initialize() {
 
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.910511,33.391734);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
 
     var html = "<table>" +
                         "<tr><td>Наименование:</td> <td><input type='text' id='name'/> </td> </tr>" +
                         "<tr><td>Адрес:</td> <td><input type='text' id='address'/></td> </tr>" +
                         "<tr><td>Тип:</td> <td><select id='type'>" +
                         "<option value='bar' SELECTED>Бар</option>" +
                         "<option value='restaurant'>Ресторан</option>" +
                         "<option value='cafe'>Кафе</option>" +
                         "</select> </td></tr>" +
                         "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Сохранить' onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr></form>";
 
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: html
    });
 
    var marker;
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
        marker && marker.setMap(null)
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: event.latLng,
          map: map
        });
  
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }); 
 
 
  }
 
 

  function saveData() {
      var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
      var address = escape(document.getElementById("address").value);
      var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
      var latlng = marker.getPosition();
 
      var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=" + name + "&address=" + address +
                "&type=" + type + "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng();
      downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
        if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
          infowindow.close();
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Данные добавлены.";
        }
      });
    }
 
    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;
 
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request.responseText, request.status);
        }
      };
 
      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }
 
    function doNothing() {}
</script> 
 
<style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
#map_canvas { float:left; width:600px; height:400px; border:1px solid #000;} 
</style>
 
</head> 
<body onload="initialize()"> 
      <div id="map_canvas"></div> 
    <div id="message"></div>

</body> 
</html>
```

PS: В скрипте падают еще какие-то ошибки, не стал разбираться с ними

Comment: Спасаибо большое..